# EXC BAD using a Range instruction

Tags: excel, vba

I'm mad because when I try to start a very basic instruction, there is a formula that doesn't work at all however this is copy pasta from another sheet, on this one the instruction is working.

Comment: Missing `)` just before `.Formula` -  `Range(Cells(2,9),Cells(1,9)).Formula`

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try.

```
Range(Cells(2,9),Cells(1,9).Value= "Big ben you virgin du mb pine ta mam's"
```

But to make it specific you should say on which sheet the Range is like.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of the sheet").Range(Cells(2,9),Cells(1,9).Value= "Big ben you virgin du mb pine ta mam's"
```

The Formula attribute is not made to put text into a cell.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, i would appreciate if you mark it as such.